# Apple push notification with an enterprise application

Tags: php, iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

we have developed an application that use push notifications by following the [very good guide created by David Mytton](http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/).

The push service worked great on the development profile. But now that it is finished we have changed to the customers distribution profile. The application is an in-house application using an Enterprise account.

We have changed the certificate on the server and we have changed to the production url as specified in the tutorial. We have also replaced the profile used when building the application and installed it to the tester iPhone. Everything seems to work on the server, and no error messages is returned but the push is never recieved on the iPhone. We are pretty clueless right now and don't know where to start debugging on this. We have checked that the tokenId is updated after replacing the profile.

Has anyone any experience in this and might know what's wrong or where to start debugging? Thanks!

Comment: Did you delete development profile app from your device before install production app build and make sure your push notification setting is enable for your app in Default Setting app ?

Comment: No, i didn't delete the old profile from the app so thanks for the tip! Unfortunately it didn't help :/ And yes, push notifications is enabled for the app in settings.

Comment: I'm curious about this, because Apple reference says "Apple Push Notification service (APNs) is available only to apps distributed through the iOS App Store or Mac App Store." (is this even still accurate??) at this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea what was wrong here but i finally got it to work..

After hours of debugging without results i threw in the towel and created a new developer certificate, app id, push sertificate and distribution profile. I cleaned the project added the new profile and replaced all files on server.

And it worked! No problems at all... Sometimes i hate being an iPhone/Apple developer :\

Comment: Did you also reboot your Windows PC? ;) Sometimes a flush just fixes those things you missed or got messed up in the process. Always frustrating but relieving in the end.

Comment: Yes, in fact i did also restart the pc :)

Answer (score 3):

A few things that you could try:

1. Make sure your phone is plugged in to a power source (sometimes not having this causes delayed notifications).
2. Use the following PHP library:

http://code.google.com/p/php-apns/

This allows you to debug the communication with the server and see where the error occurs. Specifically it allows you to debug if your token id is incorrect.

1. You could try using an incorrect token id on the server and see the behavior. Compare this with using the correct token id.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try this and see if we get some more information.

Answer (score 0):

- Any in-house distribution profile gives out a same tokenID, how ever 
  this tokenID varies across different devices.
- Other only issue could be only with the ProductionURL.
- I have also notices that the push notification reception is delayed sometimes, mostly when used with production URL.

Hope this helps.